# Execute Stored Procedure Talend

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, talend

I try to execute a stored procedure with Talend 7.1.1. That procedure is registered in DB '`SYS`' and she `TRUNCATE` the table in parameter (my table : `ODS.TEMPF_PRODUCTION`)

I put the composent `tDBSP (ORACLE)`, I connected it to my database '`SYS`' where is stored my procedure '`TRUNCATE_TABLE`' but I don't know where I need to inform my parameter `table_name`.

My component:
[image]

[image]
If someone can tell me what is missing, I would be grateful !

Comment: Just a guess, but won't the green + button under the parameters section let you add that? A quick search came up with [this guide](https://help.talend.com/reader/ezE005k1syi0pq3WAU8WyA/Or3iSV87d~xx6xzHYrUnLA), which seems to agree. (Also, you shouldn't really be creating things in the SYS schema.)

Comment: Yeah that is what i need. I'm going to post your solution with my image. Thanks you Alex Poole :)

Comment: Also I don't create anything in SYS but I need it for calling a SP (for Truncate a table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The designer:
[image]

The tDBSP conected to my DB 'SYS':
[image]

The tFixedFlowInput send the name of my table to the parameter 'table_name' from the procedure:
[image]

That's working perfectly ! Thx to Alex Poole.